# Send message notification to web service(java) from Microsoft Teams channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

My use case is when a user creates or updates a message in the Teams channel that message should come to my web service(java URL) without @mention, Please suggest me any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation here :
[Receive all channel messages with RSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-messages-with-rsc). Here you will get the notification of messages receives on channel. The samples are not yet available for JAVA. But you can get idea with C#/Node.js - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-messages-with-rsc#code-sample)

Comment: Thanks for and input and appreciate @Hunaid Hanfee-MSFT

As per the document This feature is currently available in public developer preview only.
Can you please suggest any alternate way for this?

Comment: This is only possible way available as of now.